# JSON dot notation returning different from JSON api request

Tags: arrays, json, axios

Using dot notation to access a JSON response is returning different values than what the API response is saying in my browser

I tried to access a JSON response from an axios request like so:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=US&allowCountries=US');

console.log(response.data.data.Catalog.searchStore.elements.promotions)
```

Instead of getting a response something similar to this in JSON:

```
{
    "promotions": {
        "promotionalOffers": [
            {
                "promotionalOffers": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "2023-02-02T16:00:00.000Z",
                        "endDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                        "discountSetting": {
                            "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                            "discountPercentage": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "upcomingPromotionalOffers": []
    }
}
```

I simply get this from the console log:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I might not be using dot notation to access it correctly but I have no idea. You can view the JSON response from the browser here: https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=US&allowCountries=US

Comment: `response.data.data.Catalog.searchStore.elements` is an array.

Comment: Ahh yeah that'll definitely do it. Sleep deprivation is real. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#1 Getting data from the server by `axios`.
The `elements` start `[` and end `]` is an array data.

[image]

(* I copy/paste from Browser to VS code after access URL, saved JSON data)
VS code can expand/collapse data by clicking down arrow.

#2 Filter only `promotions`
It is one of Key values of array `elements`

[image]

You can filter by Array map()

Simple example for getting title only

```
const titles = elements.map(item => { return { title : item.title }  } )
console.log(JSON.stringify(titles, null, 4))
```

```
[
    {
        "title": "Borderlands 3 Season Pass"
    },
    {
        "title": "City of Gangsters"
    },
    {
        "title": "Recipe for Disaster"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dishonored®: Death of the Outsider™"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dishonored - Definitive Edition"
    }
]
```

So this code will works for getting `promotions`

```
const axios = require('axios')

const getPromotions = async (data) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=US&allowCountries=US');
        return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
};

getPromotions()
    .then(result => {
        const promotions = result.data.Catalog.searchStore.elements.map(item => { return { promotions : item.promotions }  } )
        console.log(JSON.stringify(promotions, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    });
```

Result

```
$ node get-data.js
[
    {
        "promotions": {
            "promotionalOffers": [
                {
                    "promotionalOffers": [
                        {
                            "startDate": "2023-01-26T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "endDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "discountSetting": {
                                "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                                "discountPercentage": 30
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "startDate": "2023-01-26T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "endDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "discountSetting": {
                                "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                                "discountPercentage": 30
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "upcomingPromotionalOffers": []
        }
    },
    {
        "promotions": {
            "promotionalOffers": [
                {
                    "promotionalOffers": [
                        {
                            "startDate": "2023-02-02T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "endDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "discountSetting": {
                                "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                                "discountPercentage": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "upcomingPromotionalOffers": []
        }
    },
    {
        "promotions": {
            "promotionalOffers": [],
            "upcomingPromotionalOffers": [
                {
                    "promotionalOffers": [
                        {
                            "startDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "endDate": "2023-02-16T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "discountSetting": {
                                "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                                "discountPercentage": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "promotions": {
            "promotionalOffers": [
                {
                    "promotionalOffers": [
                        {
                            "startDate": "2023-02-02T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "endDate": "2023-02-09T16:00:00.000Z",
                            "discountSetting": {
                                "discountType": "PERCENTAGE",
                                "discountPercentage": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "upcomingPromotionalOffers": []
        }
    },
    {
        "promotions": null
    }
]
```